# In integer linear programming, how to satisfy (at least) one out of three conditions

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Suppose you are given a function which you have to optimize. You are given 3 conditions among which (at least) one has to be satisfied.
The conditions are:

x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ≤ 30,

−3x1 + 3x2 − 2x3 + x4 ≥ 40,

−x1 + x2 + 4x3 + x4 ≤ 60.

I know you have to add such a large number on the right so the condition is fulfilled as "not empty". That is why you intruduce a new variable

$$q_i = \begin{cases} 1; & the condition does not necessarily apply \ 0; & otherwise\end{cases}$$

In the end you are suppose to get something like

x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ≤ 30 + M q1

−3x1 + 3x2 − 2x3 + x4 ≥ 40 +M q2

−x1 + x2 + 4x3 + x4 ≤ 60 + M q3

However, I do not know how to find the missing M's.
Does anyone know how to conquer this problem?

Comment: What is the optimization objective?

Comment: @Reinderien you have to maximize the function (which was not given).

Answer (score 2):

- The rhs of second constraint should read `40 -M q2`
- It is better to use M1,M2,M3 as they are preferably different in size.
- The sizes of M are important. They should be as small as possible but not cut off any feasible solutions. E.g. if `x[i]∈[0,100]`, then for the first constraint `M=370`.
- I have even used sometimes extra solves to find the best value for my big-Ms.
- Many MIP solvers support **indicator constraints**. That would allow you to write: `q1=0 ==> x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ≤ 30` without any big-Ms.
- I probably should not mention this, but it is also possible to use SOS1 sets to prevent big-Ms. If you don't know what SOS sets are, ignore this bullet.

---

In another answer a wrong model (a.k.a. hack) is proposed. Here is the same model using binary variables and big-Ms:

```
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='original_model', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
x1, x2, x3, x4 = [pulp.LpVariable(name=f'x{i}', lowBound=0, upBound=100) for i in range(1,5)]
b1,b2,b3 = [pulp.LpVariable(name=f'b{i}', cat=pulp.LpBinary) for i in range(1,4)]

M = 1000
prob.addConstraint(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 <= 30 + M*b1)
prob.addConstraint(-3*x1 + 3*x2 - 2*x3 + x4 >= 40 - M*b2)
prob.addConstraint(-x1 + x2 + 4*x3 + x4 <= 60 + M*b3)

prob.addConstraint(b1+b2+b3<=2)

prob.objective = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 
print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

This produces:

```
b1 = 1.0
b2 = 0.0
b3 = 1.0
x1 = 53.333333
x2 = 100.0
x3 = 100.0
x4 = 100.0
```

with an obj of 353.33. The other model reported `x = [100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 100.0]` with an obj of 330. As we are maximizing, that is a non-optimal solution.

These types of "short-cut" models with some form of penalty are not rigorous and are often wrong. Sometimes they work on a given data set. But they fail in general. Always be very suspicious about them.

There is a theoretical reason also. The 'or' type of constraints introduce a non-convexity. We cannot reformulate an inherently non-convex model into a linear convex model. If that were the case, we would not need MIP solvers.

This also means you need to be careful with what is proposed in answers. It may look authoritative, but as in this case, it is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way I could imagine to solve this problem would be to just solve your optimization problem three times, first with only the first constraint, next with only the second constraint, and last only with the third constraint. Then you just take the best of the three solutions identified. Taking the example provided in other answers of maximizing x1+x2+x3+x4 subject to at least one of your constraints as well as bounds of [0, 100] on each variable, we might do:

```
import pulp

leq_constraints = [{"lhs": [1, 1, 1, 1], "rhs": 30},
                   {"lhs": [3, -3, 2, -1], "rhs": -40},
                   {"lhs": [-1, 1, 4, 1], "rhs": 60}]

solns = []
for constr in leq_constraints:
    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='original_model', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
    x = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(name='x', indices=range(1, 5), cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
                               lowBound=0, upBound=100)
    prob.addConstraint(sum([c*var for c, var in zip(constr["lhs"], x)]) <= constr["rhs"])
    prob.objective = x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3]
    prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
    solns.append((prob.objective.value(), [xi.value() for xi in x]))

bestSol = max(solns)
print("Best objective:", bestSol[0])
print("Best solution variable values:", bestSol[1])
```

The output confirms what others have been saying -- 353.33 is the best possible objective value.

```
# Best objective: 353.33333300000004
# Best solution variable values: [53.333333, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
```

This avoids all the hassle of thinking about big-M's, and for you it's at pretty minimal cost (solving 3 instead of 1 problems). Since you indicated in the comments that you needed to solve this by pen and paper, solving three simple problems instead of making a giant problem with big-M's and binary variables is definitely the way I would go.

That said, with more complexity to your requirements (e.g. at least 10 of 100 constraints hold) this would not be a good approach, since you would need to solve 100 choose 10 = trillions of problems. Then you would surely be better served by going the big-M route.

Answer (score -1):

Depending somewhat on your objective and decision variable bounds, there is a more compact method than big-M. Define a single slack variable to be the maximum of three different right-hand inequality sides, where the left hand is one variable; then enforce that that single constrained variable is less than the slack:

```py
import pulp

'''
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ≤ 30,       x3 <=   30 -  x1 -  x2 - x4
−3x1 + 3x2 − 2x3 + x4 ≥ 40,   x3 <= (-40 - 3x1 + 3x2 + x4)/2
−x1 + x2 + 4x3 + x4 ≤ 60.     x3 <= ( 60 +  x1 -  x2 - x4)/4
'''

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='additive_constraints', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
x = x1, x2, x3, x4 = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(name='x', indices=range(1, 5), cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
                                            lowBound=0, upBound=100)

cu = pulp.LpVariable(name='cu', cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

# cu is the max of the three RHS x3 inequalities
rhs_a =   30 -   x1 -   x2 - x4
rhs_b  = (-40 - 3*x1 + 3*x2 + x4)/2
rhs_c  = ( 60 +   x1 -   x2 - x4)/4
prob.addConstraint(cu >= rhs_a)
prob.addConstraint(cu >= rhs_b)
prob.addConstraint(cu >= rhs_c)

prob.addConstraint(x3 <= cu)

prob.objective = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 - cu
print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
x = x1, x2, x3, x4 = [xi.value() for xi in x]
cu = cu.value()

print('x =', x)
print()

print('Constraints, any of:')
print(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, '<= 30',)
print(-3*x1 + 3*x2 - 2*x3 + x4, '>= 40')
print(-x1 + x2 + 4*x3 + x4, '<= 60')
print()

print('RHS, all of:')
print(cu, '>=', rhs_a.value())
print(cu, '>=', rhs_b.value())
print(cu, '>=', rhs_c.value())
```

```
additive_constraints:
MAXIMIZE
-1*cu + 1*x_1 + 1*x_2 + 1*x_3 + 1*x_4 + 0
SUBJECT TO
_C1: cu + x_1 + x_2 + x_4 >= 30

_C2: cu + 1.5 x_1 - 1.5 x_2 - 0.5 x_4 >= -20

_C3: cu - 0.25 x_1 + 0.25 x_2 + 0.25 x_4 >= 15

_C4: - cu + x_3 <= 0

VARIABLES
cu free Continuous
x_1 <= 100 Continuous
x_2 <= 100 Continuous
x_3 <= 100 Continuous
x_4 <= 100 Continuous


Optimal - objective value 300
Optimal objective 300 - 2 iterations time 0.002
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

x = [100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 100.0]

Constraints, any of:
330.0 <= 30
40.0 >= 40
220.0 <= 60

RHS, all of:
30.0 >= -270.0
30.0 >= 30.0
30.0 >= -10.0
```

In this formulation you have to take care that `cu` has a lower objective weight than your true objective. If your decision variables are integral this is easy; if they are continuous this may require a secondary step.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem by hand? This was on my theoretical exam of Operations research, so I could only use pen and paper ...

Comment: I think the correct solution for the original problem is x = [53.33, 100, 100, 100] which is better. Your method changes the problem. This is explains why we don't use this in practice.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen since the objective is not given, (the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and) the kind of solution comparison you're attempting is impossible.

Comment: Nonsense, I used the same obj as you did.